# cqrs/ddd - What is the point of having informational Data in the write model/aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am wondering whether it makes sense to not store informational Data inside the write model database. By informational Data I mean data that is not directly used for any decision making in the write model.

For example take a Product in a Sales context. It would have a name that can be updated. But other than that, the name doesnt serve any purpose. So wouldn't it be enough to have an event fire everytime the name is updated and just project it in the read side?

Especially when we use DDD and want to model aggregates, that kind of information that can be just updated but is not involved in any other business rules, could be omitted in the write side, what do you think? In many examples of DDD I even see that this informational data is copied to other bounded contexts and just duplicated but it also isnt involved in any business rules.

Comment: can you clarify your question a bit? Do you have more than a single DDD context? Are you saying the sales context has a read method which should return a name but a write method which shouldn't be able to update it? How would any product in that context get a name?

Comment: The write model should have a command to update the name, but the name will only be persisted on the read side and not the write model, e.g. write side sends an event that name was updated and read side updates its model. I used DDD as an example because aggregates should only contain data they need to fulfill state changes. A name is only relevant for the user to view it but not for any transactions in the write model.

Comment: sorry im not sure i follow, surely one of the transactions is updating the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is some underlying misunderstanding in your question.

With CQRS we essentially have two copies of the same data

1. A master database where we do all the changes
2. Multiple read databases where we can get data without adding load to the master database. Note this database might be (slightly) out of date.

So the write model has all the same information as the read model, even though it might be split up differently. Instead of ProductName lets use Account Balance, for our example.

On the write side I have a command `AddFunds(string accountId, int amount)` its got a very basic data structure with just those two fields, but when it's processed it adds the data to the WriteDB with `insert into funds ({accountid},{amount})`. The account table has the rest of the account information.

On the read side I have a Query `GetAccount(string id)` which returns an Account ReadModel:

```
AccountWithTotal
{
  id,
  TotalFunds
}
```

Where TotalFunds is the sum of all the funds that have been added.

The clever bit is this is not populated by running a query on the WriteDB  `select *, sum(funds.amount) from account left join funds...` This would be slow, instead an online job runs every night and populates a denormalized table on the ReadDB which is then just read with `select accountid, TotalFunds from AccountWithTotal`

Both sides have all Account and Fund information, but on the Write side its split into `UpdateAccount` and `AddFund` whereas the read side has `AccountWithTotal`

If we take this across to you Product.Name example, you *could* split it the same and have a separate `UpdateProductName` command, but the Write Model as a whole, would still have product name in there somewhere. Maybe you would have a NameHistory table?

Given the nature of `Name` you would really only expect a single name, compared to `Funds` where you would expect many transactions. so it seems like it would be a normal choice to just have it as a property of the Product Write Model, even if it was rarely used.

Comment: but what about when we want to model the write side more domain driven/behaviour driven. The domain aggregate doesn't need the productName to run any commands. It doesnt matter what the productName was before, the update method should just update it, aka create a DomainEvent that it was updated. Then the consumers who are interested in this event, can do whatever they want with that event. E.g. the read model can update its

Comment: im not sure how that would work. say you forward the "updatename" command to the read servers. Do you expect them to write that information? thats exactly what you are trying to avoid with CQRS, how are you gona sync them all?

Comment: also confused about how DDD fits in with this question and CRQS more generally tbh. You would expect a single `Product` model with DDD defined by the business concept of a Product, not whats fast to read or write. You could still use CQRS, but the read and write models would be the same, or at least more similar

Comment: are you mixing CQRS and Event Sourcing?

Comment: an alternative way to ask my question would be something like: In CQRS is the command side the single point of truth, or can it be splitted between read side and command side? But I guess from your answers and your confusion about my questions, in cqrs the command side is the only source of truth for all data.

Comment: yes if you update the read side then the commands and queries aren't segregated. Perhaps there is some clever way to do it with streaming databases but it would be unusual

Answer (score 1):

> So wouldn't it be enough to have an event fire every time the name is updated and just project it in the read side?

Maybe - but you should probably be thinking about what is really going on, and trying to design your system so that it is consistent with that reality.

One possibility is that names aren't really under the authority of the system you are building; that naming happens *somewhere else* (perhaps some human picks the names?) and all we are really doing in our system is caching the name we have been provided, along with additional metadata that will allow us to eventually perform the joins that we need for our reporting.

In such a design, we would not treat the name as part of the "product aggregate", because it plays no role in the sales processes that the aggregate participates in.

Another possibility is that there is an aggregate where tracking the product name makes sense, but it's not here in the sales context, but over there in the marketing/branding context.

Note that if the real aggregate is over there, then over here we should be treating that as information from somewhere else, that we cached at some point in the past.

---

Recommended reading:

- Data on the Outside vs Data on the Inside ([Pat Helland, 2005](http://cidrdb.org/cidr2005/papers/P12.pdf))

Comment: regarding your last two paragraphs. When the name is needed in the marketing context, why would we also cache it in the sales context if the sales context doesn't really need it?